# WPF: How do I set the focus on a datagrid to a specific row?

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I would like to set the focus on the first row of a data grid.

This is what I have so far:

```
Keyboard.Focus(ResultsGrid)
If result.Count > 0 Then
    ResultsGrid.SelectedIndex = 0
End If
```

This will set the focus to the datagrid, but not the row itself.

Answer (score 23):

After selecting the row you will have to set the focus on the row in the following way:

```
ResultsGrid.SelectedIndex = index;
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)ResultsGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

Comment: my program is interrupted because the variable 'row' is null.. any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Remeber that index is base 0 (0 is first row). You can add a check if row != null to avoid the exception.

Comment: @AllanRuin Look at the answer of this question:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551197)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yourDataGrid.SelectedItem = yourDataGrid.Items[i];
```

Comment: It is complaining that row is null.

Comment: ItemContainerGenerator.Status is NotStarted. Is there a way to manually kick it off?

Comment: Updated my answer. It's easier than I thought.

Comment: That has the same problem I had using `SelectedIndex = 0`.

Comment: In my application it gave focus to the row and not just the datagrid.

Comment: dataGrid.Focus(); is also work for focus in datagrid and arrows keys not working then what if we want to focus on rows as well because of this our arrow keys will work any solution please ?