# WPF: control.ItemContainerGenerator.Status is NotStarted. How do I tell it to start now?

Tags: wpf

My controls .ItemContainerGenerator.Status is NotStarted. How do I tell it to start now and wait until it is completed?

Comment: See my updated answer to your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480850/wpf-how-do-i-set-the-focus-on-a-datagrid/2480901#2480901

Answer (score 9):

You may want to start the generator manually if you doing some syncronous operation - I had to generate the result view to meassure it before chunking it up on pages.

```
   IItemContainerGenerator generator = (child as ListContent).ItemContainerGenerator;
   GeneratorPosition position = generator.GeneratorPositionFromIndex(0);
   using (generator.StartAt(position, GeneratorDirection.Forward,true))
   {
                        foreach (object o in (child as ListContent).Items)
                        {
                            DependencyObject dp = generator.GenerateNext();
                            generator.PrepareItemContainer(dp);
                        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind and show the ItemsControl.  The ItemContainerGenerator will start and generate items as part of the data binding cycle.

If you really need to manually start the generator, you may be able to do so by calling IItemContainerGenerator.StartAt.  This is an explicit interface implementation so you will need to cast the ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator property, e.g. `((IItemContainerGenerator)(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator)).StartAt(...);`.  But manually starting the generator is very rarely necessary in application code.

Comment: Alas this doesn't do what I want. While it does indeed start the item generation, it doesn't wait until they are complete.

Comment: I guess you could poll for GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated, but it depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged
```

event to handle when status are changed