# Styles not applying to headless wpf control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

**Goal**

I have a WPF window with some nested `ItemsControls`. I need to extract the items into bitmaps but without actually displaying the window.  So far, I have gotten through some of the hurdles of rendering the visual tree without displaying the actual window.

**Problem**

My problem is that the output doesn't have the styles applied to it.

**Things I've tried**

- If I show the window first, then get the bitmaps, then close the window everything looks fine (styles are all applied).  Though, I don't consider this "hack" to be acceptable but more a form of troubleshooting.
- Wrapping the `ContentPresenter` in a `ViewBox` and doing a `.Measure()` and `.Arrange()`  but that didn't help

I've referenced [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481033/wpf-control-itemcontainergenerator-status-is-notstarted-how-do-i-tell-it-to-st) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768945/wpf-force-to-build-visual-tree) to get me closer to getting things right, but alas the styles still aren't applied.  I assume that I'm missing some sort of step that forces the styles to be applied.  Any help would be appreciated.  FYI, I'm using .Net 4 in VS 2012.

Apologies if bits of this code don't quite match up.  As mentioned above there are a bunch of nested ItemsControls and for the sake of brevity I've tried to slim everything down to make it easier to follow.

**Setting up the control**

```
ucAncillary ancillaryControl = new ucAncillary(AncillaryGroups);
ancillaryControl.ApplyTemplate();
ancillaryControl.UpdateLayout();
ancillaryControl.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
ancillaryControl.Arrange(new Rect(ancillaryControl.DesiredSize));

//AncillaryGroups is the name of the ItemsControl that I want the items from
ancillaryControl.AncillaryGroups.generateContainers();

foreach (var group in AncillaryGroups)
{
    var groupControl = this.AncillaryGroups.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(group) as ContentPresenter;
    groupControl.ApplyTemplate();

    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)groupControl.DesiredSize.Width, (int)groupControl.DesiredSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    rtb.Render(groupControl);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
    encoder.Save(stream);

    type.RenderedBitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
}
```

**The GenerateContainers function mentioned above**

```
public static void generateContainers(this ItemsControl c)
{
    IItemContainerGenerator generator = c.ItemContainerGenerator;
    GeneratorPosition position = generator.GeneratorPositionFromIndex(0);
    using (generator.StartAt(position, GeneratorDirection.Forward, true))
    {
        foreach (object o in c.Items)
        {
            DependencyObject dp = generator.GenerateNext();
            generator.PrepareItemContainer(dp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to measure and arrange the new controls again before rendering:

```
var groupControl = ...;
groupControl.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
groupControl.Arrange(new Rect(groupControl.DesiredSize));
```

This is by memory, I'll double check myself and update this if needed.

Comment: That was exactly it!  I could have sworn that I had that in at one point but I must not have.  Thank you very much!