# How can I get the DataGridRow from the DataRowView?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have created a WPF application that loads 2 DataGrids with data from SqlClient DataTables.  I have the method below that compares the two tables.  It was working fine, but I must have changed something in the code that broke it.  Now the dataGridRow1 and dataGridRow2 variables are always null.  How can I get the DataGridRow from the DataRowView?

```
    private void CompareDataTables(string primaryKey)
    {
        foreach (DataRowView dataRowView1 in DataGrid1.ItemsSource)
        {
            DataGridRow dataGridRow1 = DataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataRowView1) as DataGridRow;
            if (dataGridRow1 != null)
            {
                int primaryKeyValue1 = (int)dataRowView1.Row[primaryKey];
                foreach (DataRowView dataRowView2 in DataGrid2.ItemsSource)
                {
                    //DataRowView dataRowView2 = (DataRowView)dataGridRow2.Item;
                    int primaryKeyValue2 = (int)dataRowView2.Row[primaryKey];
                    if (primaryKeyValue1 == primaryKeyValue2)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridColumn column in DataGrid1.Columns)
                        {
                            DataGridRow dataGridRow2 = DataGrid2.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataRowView2) as DataGridRow;
                            if (dataGridRow2 != null)
                            {
                                FrameworkElement frameworkElement1 = column.GetCellContent(dataGridRow1);
                                FrameworkElement frameworkElement2 = GetFrameworkElement(DataGrid2, dataGridRow2, (String)column.Header);
                                if (frameworkElement1 is TextBlock && frameworkElement2 is TextBlock)
                                {
                                    TextBlock textBlock1 = frameworkElement1 as TextBlock;
                                    TextBlock textBlock2 = frameworkElement2 as TextBlock;
                                    if (textBlock1.Text != textBlock2.Text)
                                    {
                                        textBlock1.Background = Brushes.LightSalmon;
                                        textBlock2.Background = Brushes.LightSalmon;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps whatever is returned by `DataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` is either null, or something other than a `DataGridRow`.  I'd inspect what's being returned by that method.

Comment: Yes, ContainerFromItem is returning null.  My question is what else can I do to get the DataGridRow?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem, please use grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex function, because Datadrid is using virtulization so Item is not generated at that time.

Comment: Thanks, I tried ContainerFromIndex, but it still returns null.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix the problem.  Place this line of code before ContinerFromItem:

DataGrid1.UpdateLayout();

Who would've guessed?  Here's a link to another question where I found this answer:

[ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem() returns null while VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184172/itemcontainergenerator-containerfromitem-returns-null-while-virtualizingstackp)