# WPF TreeView with virtualization - select and bring item into view

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I've been working with WPF treeview for a bit recently and I'm having a really awful time trying to get the selected item to show up on the screen when the user uses a search function that sets the IsSelected property on the backing object.

Currently my approach is using the method in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34620549/800318

```
    private void FocusTreeViewNode(TreeViewEntry node)
    {
        if (node == null) return;
        var nodes = (IEnumerable<TreeViewEntry>)LeftSide_TreeView.ItemsSource;
        if (nodes == null) return;

        var stack = new Stack<TreeViewEntry>();
        stack.Push(node);
        var parent = node.Parent;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            stack.Push(parent);
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }

        var generator = LeftSide_TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator;
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var dequeue = stack.Pop();
            LeftSide_TreeView.UpdateLayout();

            var treeViewItem = (TreeViewItem)generator.ContainerFromItem(dequeue);
            if (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                treeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (treeViewItem == null)
                {
                    //This is being triggered when it shouldn't be
                    Debugger.Break();
                }
                treeViewItem.IsSelected = true;
            }
            treeViewItem.BringIntoView();
            generator = treeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator;
        }
    }
```

`TreeViewEntry` is my backing data type, which has a reference to its parent node. `Leftside_TreeView` is the virtualized TreeView that is bound to the list of my objects. Turning off virtualization is not an option as performance is really bad with it off.

When I search for an object and the backing data object is found, I call this FocusTreeViewNode() method with the object as its parameter. It will typically work on the first call, selecting the object and bringing it into view.

Upon doing the search a second time, the node to select is passed in, however the ContainerFromItem() call when the stack is emptied (so it is trying to generate the container for the object itself) returns null. When I debug this I can see the object I am searching for in the ContainerGenerator's items list, but for some reason it is not being returned. I looked up all the things to do with UpdateLayout() and other things, but I can't figure this out.

Some of the objects in the container may be off the page even after the parent node is brought into view - e.g. an expander has 250 items under it and only 60 are rendered at time. Could this be an issue?

**Update**

Here is a sample project that makes a virtualized treeview that shows this issue. https://github.com/Mgamerz/TreeViewVirtualizingErrorDemo

Build it in VS, then in the search box enter something like 4. Press search several times and it will throw an exception saying the container was null, even though if you open the `generator` object you can clearly see it's in the generator.

Comment: Do you have a small reproducing project?

Comment: Yes, I can create one I believe, give me a few hours as the one I am on is too complicated to shrink down.

Comment: Done - added a link to a github project that showcases the issue

Answer (score 7):

Like many other aspects of WPF development, this operation can be handled by using the MVVM design pattern.

Create a ViewModel class, including an IsSelected property, which holds the data for each tree item.

Bringing the selected item into view can then be handled by an attached property

```
public static class perTreeViewItemHelper
{
    public static bool GetBringSelectedItemIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
        return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(BringSelectedItemIntoViewProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBringSelectedItemIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(BringSelectedItemIntoViewProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BringSelectedItemIntoViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BringSelectedItemIntoView",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(perTreeViewItemHelper),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, BringSelectedItemIntoViewChanged));

    private static void BringSelectedItemIntoViewChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(args.NewValue is bool))
            return;

        var item = obj as TreeViewItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OnTreeViewItemSelected;
        else
            item.Selected -= OnTreeViewItemSelected;
    }

    private static void OnTreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        item?.BringIntoView();

        // prevent this event bubbling up to any parent nodes
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This can then be used as part of a style for TreeViewItems

```
<Style x:Key="perTreeViewItemContainerStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

    <!-- Link the properties of perTreeViewItemViewModelBase to the corresponding ones on the TreeViewItem -->
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />

    <!-- Include the two "Scroll into View" behaviors -->
    <Setter Property="vhelp:perTreeViewItemHelper.BringSelectedItemIntoView" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="vhelp:perTreeViewItemHelper.BringExpandedChildrenIntoView" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                          MinWidth="14" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  ClickMode="Press"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource perExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" />

                    <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                          Margin="0,2"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          ContentSource="Header" />

                    </Border>

                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <!--  Use the same colors for a selected item, whether the TreeView is focussed or not  -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource perTreeViewItemContainerStyle}" />
</Style>
```

More details and a full example of usage on my recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).

**Update 13 Oct**

The blog post has been amended for when running in standard (non-lazy loading mode). The associated demo project shows a nested data structure of over 400,000 elements being displayed in a TreeView, and yet the response for selecting any random node is instantaneous.

Comment: While not as easy as I was hoping (I don't see how a novice could ever figure this out) your blog post is quite handy and very detailed, thanks.

Comment: It's taken me many years of virtually full time exposure to WPF / MVVM to get to a point where I'm happy with the platform and to have built up a library of useful constructs like this one. The key to remember is WPF is the complete opposite in design paradigm to say winforms. Techniques such as event handlers and endless code behind may work well in other UI platforms don't work so well in WPF.

Comment: The learning situation is not helped when two best selling books for WPF (Adam Nathan & Matthew MacDonald) still don't make more than a passing mention of the the MVVM design pattern.

Comment: While this worked better than my previous attempts, on items with lots of children (say 300 children) items in the middle will return null - I assume because we are getting the end of the list and the middle items are not generated yet.

Comment: @Mgamerz I've just updated my blog post. The new demo project demonstrates displaying a nested data structure with over 400,000 elements in a TreeView, and yet the response for selecting any random node is instantaneous.

Comment: Implemented this, unfortunately it also does not work reliably when virtualization is turned on. A call to containerfromitem() does not return anything, and as such items cannot be brought into view. Once the first BringIntoView() fails, all subsequent calls typically fail too. The search continues...

Answer (score 3):

It's quite difficult to get the `TreeViewItem` for a given data item, in all cases, especially the virtualized ones.

Fortunately, Microsoft has provided a helper function for us here [How to: Find a TreeViewItem in a TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ff407130(v=vs.100)) that I have adapted so it doesn't need a custom `VirtualizingStackPanel` class (requires .NET Framework 4.5 or higher, for older versions, consult the link above).

Here is how you can replace your `FocusTreeViewNode` method:

```
private void FocusTreeViewNode(MenuItem node)
{
    if (node == null)
        return;

    var treeViewItem = GetTreeViewItem(tView, node);
    treeViewItem?.BringIntoView();
}


public static TreeViewItem GetTreeViewItem(ItemsControl container, object item)
{
    if (container == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));

    if (item == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

    if (container.DataContext == item)
        return container as TreeViewItem;

    if (container is TreeViewItem && !((TreeViewItem)container).IsExpanded)
    {
        container.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsExpandedProperty, true);
    }

    container.ApplyTemplate();
    if (container.Template.FindName("ItemsHost", container) is ItemsPresenter itemsPresenter)
    {
        itemsPresenter.ApplyTemplate();
    }
    else
    {
        itemsPresenter = FindVisualChild<ItemsPresenter>(container);
        if (itemsPresenter == null)
        {
            container.UpdateLayout();
            itemsPresenter = FindVisualChild<ItemsPresenter>(container);
        }
    }

    var itemsHostPanel = (Panel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itemsPresenter, 0);
    var children = itemsHostPanel.Children;
    var virtualizingPanel = itemsHostPanel as VirtualizingPanel;
    for (int i = 0, count = container.Items.Count; i < count; i++)
    {
        TreeViewItem subContainer;
        if (virtualizingPanel != null)
        {
            // this is the part that requires .NET 4.5+
            virtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoViewPublic(i);
            subContainer = (TreeViewItem)container.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        }
        else
        {
            subContainer = (TreeViewItem)container.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            subContainer.BringIntoView();
        }

        if (subContainer != null)
        {
            TreeViewItem resultContainer = GetTreeViewItem(subContainer, item);
            if (resultContainer != null)
                return resultContainer;

            subContainer.IsExpanded = false;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(Visual visual) where T : Visual
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
    {
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i) is Visual child)
        {
            if (child is T item)
                return item;

            item = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (item != null)
                return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have tested this, and while it does work, the performance on large trees is pretty bad - we're talking over 60 seconds on trees with like 20 or 30 thousand nodes. Maybe there is a way to optimize it or something since we know the parents of the item we are trying to focus?

Comment: @Mgamerz - mmhhh... true. The problems seems to come from a 20000 loop on BringIndexIntoViewPublic. Not sure how to do better w/o getting problems. The problem is the virtualized panel optimizes UI, not search. Maybe you should change the way you do thing. For example, you could build a dictionary of TreeViewItems from Items using a custom TreeView: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c64fdd6b-1f91-4e4f-ada3-e100aff83a00/custom-treeviewitem?forum=wpf