# Reasons for DataGrid ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex's Row return as null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, itemcontainergenerator

My intention to keep focus on the Selected Row of DataGrid. For this i searched and found the link [How do I set the focus on a datagrid to a specific row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480850/wpf-how-do-i-set-the-focus-on-a-datagrid-to-a-specific-row).. When i tried the same in my proj, i found the row always return's null..

I goggled for that too and got the [link...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591391/why-itemcontainergenerator-containerfromindex-returns-null-and-how-to-avoid-th) Here i haven't used Virtualizing, more over i have turned off the Virtualizing.. Still am facing the same.. May i know some reasons why this returns null?

```
<DataGrid Name="DGrid"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Reports,
                                        NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                  MouseDoubleClick="DGrid_MouseDoubleClick"
                  PreviewKeyDown="DGrid_PreviewKeyDown"
                  SelectionChanged="DGrid_SelectionChanged"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="CellEditingStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DueStatus"
                                        Width="16"
                                        CellStyle="{StaticResource CellEditingStyle}"
                                        SortMemberPath="OverDue">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <!--  ReSharper disable Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved - This will be generated at Runtime  -->
                                <Image Name="ImgOvr"
                                       Width="16"
                                       Height="16"
                                       Source="/VersadexMreUs;component/Images/signal_flag_red.png"
                                       Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextToVisiblity},
                                                            Path=OverDue}" />
                                <!--  ReSharper restore Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved  -->
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ArrestStatus"
                                        Width="16"
                                        CellStyle="{StaticResource CellEditingStyle}"
                                        SortMemberPath="ArrestMade">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <!--  ReSharper disable Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved - This will be generated at Runtime  -->
                                <Image Width="16"
                                       Height="16"
                                       Source="/VersadexMreUs;component/Images/car_compact_red.png"
                                       Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextToVisiblity},
                                                            Path=ArrestMade}" />
                                <!--  ReSharper restore Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved  -->
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="IncompleteStatus"
                                        Width="16"
                                        CellStyle="{StaticResource CellEditingStyle}"
                                        SortMemberPath="InComplete">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <!--  ReSharper disable Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved - This will be generated at Runtime  -->
                                <Image Width="16"
                                       Height="16"
                                       Source="/VersadexMreUs;component/Images/document_warning.png"
                                       Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextToVisiblity},
                                                            Path=InComplete}" />
                                <!--  ReSharper restore Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved  -->
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RptStatus"
                                    MinWidth="120"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=StatusMessage,
                                                      Converter={StaticResource TextToUpper}}"
                                    Header="Status" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RptDesc"
                                    MinWidth="200"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=Description,
                                                      Converter={StaticResource TextToUpper}}"
                                    Header="Report Description" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RptState"
                                    MinWidth="250"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentState,
                                                      Converter={StaticResource TextToUpper}}"
                                    Header="Current State" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RptOfficer"
                                    MinWidth="180"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=OfficerName,
                                                      Converter={StaticResource TextToUpper}}"
                                    Header="Reporting Officer" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RptDate"
                                    MinWidth="83"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=SubmitDate,
                                                      Converter={StaticResource TextToUpper}}"
                                    Header="Submit Date" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I tried in a sample app (VS2012, .NET 4.5) and row was never null for me, that's why I wanted to see XAML.

Comment: Did you disable the VirtualizingStackPanel? To guarantee it isn't being used I would install WPF Snoop and attached to your application, you can then view what container is being used as it does sound like it is still using the VSP. I believe you need to set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to false to prevent Virtualizing.

Comment: It is difficult to determine the problem without seeing how you have set up your data grid and the code you are using to access the row. Can you post an example of your issue?

Comment: @Bijington: Code was updated..

Comment: I added your xaml to a blank wpf application, using WPF Snoop you can see that the ItemsPresenter inside still has VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing set to True, I have played around with a few ideas but I haven't been able to turn it off so far

Comment: `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` you could see that this doesn't disables the Visualizing...

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using to access and use the row?

Comment: same code which is given in the 1st link...